# Error: read ECONNRESET | Error conexion Node.js with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

I am trying to connect the application based on nodejs(backend) and vuejs(frontend) with my database SQL.

Both have their own domains and I have a database according to the premium plan from Hostinger. However, I can't connect the nodejs with SQL and I got this error:

It there something that I should do? I've never seen this error before or something like that

> node:events:491
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>
> ```
> at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
> at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/joao/Documentos/projetos/routing-software/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
> at Protocol.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Protocol._delegateError (/home/joao/Documentos/projetos/routing-software/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
> at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/home/joao/Documentos/projetos/routing-software/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:371:10)
> at Connection._handleNetworkError (/home/joao/Documentos/projetos/routing-software/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   errno: -104,   code:
> ```
>
> 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read',   fatal: true } [nodemon] app crashed
>
> - waiting for file changes before starting...

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

// routes
const authRouter = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const addressesExampleRouter = require("./routes/addressesExampleRoutes");

// config
const dbName = "databaseRoutering"
const port = 5000;

const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER
const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter)
app.use("/api/user", userRouter)
app.use("/api/address", addressesExampleRouter)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Rota teste"})
})

// mongoDB connection
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@cluster0.06ovsjg.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
);

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host_is_correct",
    user: "user_is_correct",
    password: "password_is_correct",
    database: "database_is_correct",
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("error connecting to MySQL server: " + err.stack);
      return;
    }
    console.log("connected to MySQL server as id " + db.threadId);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter)
app.use("/api/user", userRouter)
app.use("/api/address", addressesExampleRouter)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Rota teste"})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Our variable ${process.env.MY_VARIABLE}`)
    cons
```

ole.log(`Backend is running on port ${port}`)
})

Comment: If the backend and the database are on the same host you might need to use localhost:port instead of host:port

Comment: actually the database have the same IP from the frontend, not the backend...

Comment: So I am using the remote connection from Hostigner! Any IP can access this database

Comment: Make sure the port is open on the host